# Buffer Size Error after publishing Wcf Service to a Remote Server

Tags: c#, wcf, enums, buffer, iis-8.5

Just created a WCF Service that sends files to clients as buffer/stream. And testing it with a client project. At first; when I debug the service on localhost, got that error:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element

Since I increased the maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize values of Client.config from WCF Test Tool; the error was gone. Service returns the buffer with full size.

Then I published the service to the remote server via copy&paste after publishing to file system. When debugging from server and calling the same function; service returns empty buffer.

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="67108864"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="LargeBufferBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="67108864"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileOperationService" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="67108864" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" transferMode="StreamedRequest">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="67108864" maxStringContentLength="67108864" maxArrayLength="67108864" maxBytesPerRead="67108864" maxNameTableCharCount="67108864"/>
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="LargeBufferBehavior" name="EbysIntegrationService.FileOperationService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileOperationService" contract="EbysIntegrationService.IFileOperationService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <client>
      <endpoint address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileOperationService"
          contract="EbysIntegrationService.IFileOperationService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileOperationService" />
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

---

One more problem similar to this:

Defined an enum just below the Service Contract Interface:

```
[DataContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(FileType))]
public static class CompositeType
{
    public enum FileType
    { 
        [EnumMember]
        SystemFile = 1,
        [EnumMember]
        Physical = 2,
        [EnumMember]
        Invalid = 3,
        [EnumMember]
        Other = 4
    }
}
```

One of the WCF functions returns List with a string value and a FileType object. No problem on local test; return value of List has several elements but the same function on the remote server returns an empty List. Can't fix it yet and need help.

---

Do I miss a setting on web.config or IIS of remote server? Is it about the permissions of server? Should I make any change on my codes? (File System and Database cridentials are correct, other functions are working correctly)

ps. Sorry If I break the rules of typing format.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the maxBufferSize on server to resolve this error.

```
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" 
             maxBufferSize="20000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
             maxArrayLength="200000000"
             maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Have those settings already but not working. Byte array is still empty